# Django form validation in template

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Django project with many standard HTML forms.

And now I want to make another form to upload documents. I found solution using django-forms. So for me it is just a simple class:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='',
    )
    description = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Description:',
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':50}),
    )
```

I want to add emptyness check to Textarea field. There is a possibility to add "required" parameter in CharField constructor. But in this case page will allow POST and I should write extra code after "form.is_valid()" check and use "form.description.errors" to display my error message.
And I want behaviour similar to my other forms. Something like

```
<textarea name="action" required rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

In this case I can't even do POST without non-empty textarea. And more important I have error display as I like.

Is there a possibility to make such form with django-forms? Also is there a possibility to make similar behaviour to FileField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `required` attribute just like you have added `rows` or `cols`:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
        label='',
        required=True, # just in case someone doesn't submit using form 
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'required': 'required'}),
    )
    description = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Description:',
        required=True, # just in case someone doesn't submit using form 
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 50, 'required': 'required'}),
    )
```

Please note the use of `forms.ClearableFileInput` widget for `FileField` because that is what's defined as the default widget for `FileField`.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed! Is there a way to make similar in-HTML validation for a FileField for file upload?